# Getting the selected filter from the multiselect column with yadcf

Tags: yadcf

Hi I am using yadcf with datatables which allows me to do multiselect column filtering and that makes me happy. Now I want to display my selected values in the filter as tags to a separate search bar. How do I grab the selected values in my multiselect column filter? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `exGetColumnFilterVal` method, like this:

```
yadcf.exGetColumnFilterVal(oTable,1);
```

See relevant docs (from yadcf js file)

```
* exGetColumnFilterVal
                Description:        Allows to retrieve  column current filtered value (support ALL filter types!!!)
                Arguments:          table_arg: (variable of the datatable),
                                    column number:  column number from which we want the value
                Usage example:      yadcf.exGetColumnFilterVal(oTable,1);
                Return value:       String (for simple filter) / Object (for range filter) with from and to properties / Array of strings for multi_select filter
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, will check that out!